# Join tables to get the empty rows

Tags: sql, join, merge, google-bigquery

I have one table containing stock per day (stock) and another containing all the locations (locations). The goods tables only has locations that are filled, but I also need empty shelves for calculating averages and such. That is why I want to join both dataframes, so that I also get the empty ones).

The locations table looks like:

```
Locations
A
B
C
```

The stock table looks like:

```
Date       Location quantity
2021-01-01 A        5
2021-01-01 B        5
2021-01-01 A        5
2021-01-02 A        5
2021-01-02 A        5
```

What I would like:

```
Date       Location quantity
2021-01-01 A        5
2021-01-01 B        5
2021-01-01 A        5
2021-01-01 C        0 <-- new because on 01-01, there was no C
2021-01-02 A        5
2021-01-02 A        5
2021-01-02 B        0 <-- new because on 01-02, there was no C
2021-01-02 C        0 <-- new because on 01-02, there was no C
```

There are more than a million rows in the locations table alone. What further makes it complicated are the duplications (multiple products in the same location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and `left join` to bring in the data:

```
select d.date, l.location, coalesce(s.quantity, 0)
from (select distinct date from stock) d cross join
     locations l left join
     stock s
     on s.date = d.date and s.location = l.location;
```

You may have another source of dates, or can generate them using an array.

Note:  This construct is often used to return exactly one row per location and date:

```
select d.date, l.location, coalesce(sum(s.quantity), 0)
from (select distinct date from stock) d cross join
     locations l left join
     stock s
     on s.date = d.date and s.location = l.location
group by 1, 2;
```

Comment: fair enough, didn't know it worked that way

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach (less joins ...)

```
select date, location, sum(quantity) as quantity
from (
    select date, location, quantity 
    from stock 
    union all
    select date, location, 0 as quantity
    from (select distinct date from stock), locations  
)
group by date, location
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]